# C# - Windows Forms Plot 3D Graph

Tags: c#, matlab, plot

I want to plot a robot position in the x,y,z space. I already have the coordinates.

I'm trying to use chart from windows forms and enabling area3dstyle. The problem is that I cant configure the Z Axis.

There isnt any AxisZ.Maximum or Minimium option.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 50;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 50;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
```

Is there a better way to plot in 3d? Maybe linking matlab plot to visual studio. Is that possible?

Something like this:

https://youtu.be/AfTDpJiuNrk?t=29

Comment: Chart doesn't support 3d plot. The 3d-styles are just that, pseudo 3d-styles of 2d plots.

Comment: damn it :/ . Do you have any idea how can I plot my robot in 3d space?

Comment: Projecting a 3d coordinate is not too hard, but a good-looking and versatile (scaling, turning..)  chart is a much larger task. I would google for libs..